# Rails6 Action Text 本番環境での画像保存エラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

Rails6でAction Textを入れました。

開発環境でlocalには画像を保存できるのですが、本番環境でAmazon S3に保存しようとすると画像のような横のラインがアップロード時にブラウザ画面に表示され、保存できません。
開発環境の画像保存先をAmazon S3に変えると同様の事象が発生します。

Heorokuを使用しており、以下リンク先を参考に設定しましたが、どうにもうまくできず、原因がわかりません。

[Heroku+ActiveStorage+Amazon S3 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ryota-0906/items/a1be860e7e8f840c1bf5)

何か解決のための取っ掛かりがわかりましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ブラウザ経由ではなく一度 rails console からアップロード処理部分だけを試してみてはいかがでしょう

Comment: Amazon S3のCORSの設定で解決しました。